# Angular Disable Tab

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I wish to apply a class to a tab which will disable it.

For the the CSS I am using

```
.not-active {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Before seeing the tabbed page, the user is presented with several check boxes. If a check box is not checked, this tab will have the .not-active class applied to it.

For my tabs I have

```
 <nav id='tabs'>
        <ul>
            <li 
                ng-repeat='tab in tabs'
                ng-class='{"tab-current":isActiveTab(tab.url)}'
                ng-click='onClickTab(tab)'>
                <a></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </

 nav>
```

At the moment I apply the tab-current class when isActiveTab returns true.

However I am a little unsure as what the best approach would be to add the .not-active class based on a checkbox not being selected.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you already looked at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the `tip` property with your checkboxes (for example `tip.isDisabled`). Then it will be really easy to disable tab in your `onClickTab` callback, you can do there something like this:

```
$scope.onClickTab = function(tab){
    if (tab.isDisabled) return;
    // do something here
}
```

How to change `tip.isDisabled` property? Just use appropriate `ng-model` for your checkbox:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='tab in tabs'>
            <input type=checkbox ng-model='tip.isDisabled'>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkbox model as an expression inside the `ng-class` to apply `not-active` class conditionally. Like

```
   <nav id='tabs'>
        <ul>
            <li
                ng-repeat='tab in tabs'
                ng-class='{"tab-current":isActiveTab(tab.url),'not-active':!checkboxmodel}'
                ng-click='onClickTab(tab)'>
                <a></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Where `checkboxmodel` is the `ng-model` of your checkbox.

Comment: If I have three checkboxes, should I use three seperate models?

Comment: So should the condition then be 'not-active': !checkboxmodel1 || !checkboxmodel2 || !checkboxmodel3' ?

Comment: Do you want to apply **not-active** class if at-least one of them is checked?

Comment: Sorry think I haven't explained it well. Each check box represents a tab on the next page. If the check-box is not checked, that tab will have the not-active class applied to it.

Comment: How is checkbox related with tab ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96974/discussion-between-user2085143-and-vvk).